# PHPMailer can't send a message to a tracking device

Tags: php, mysql, text, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send text messages. I have a device that I can send commands to with SMS. The device has a tmobile sim card and a tmobile phone number. When I send the email, I send it to the device as XXXXXXXXXX@tmomail.net. For some reason, I don't think the devices are accepting the commands. For example, if I want the device to run for 2 minutes i would send the text command $SLEEP=2. When I use PHPMailer and type the same thing to my regular phone, I get the text no problem. (XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net). Any ideas? I've attached my code below.

```
$bk = '$SLEEP='.$sleep;
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $txt= $row["devicePhoneNumber"]. "@tmomail.net";
   }


   $phpMail = new PHPMailer();
   $phpMail->isSMTP();
   $phpMail->SMTPDebug = 2;
   $phpMail->IsHTML(true);
   $phpMail->Username = 'XXX';
   $phpMail->Password = 'XXX';
   $phpMail->From = "";
   $phpMail->FromName = "";
   $phpMail->Subject = "";
   $phpMail->Body = $bk;
   $phpMail->AddAddress($txt);
   $phpMail->AddAddress('XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net');


   $phpMail->Send();
```

Comment: Yes. It send successfully to an email and to my regular number which is the @txt.att.net above.

Comment: I know sending emails is free, but have you considered using Twilio or Nexmo (they're services specifically built for sending text messages)?

Comment: Yeah I've looked into them. I'm just trying to cut down a few costs. I realize it's a small cost.

Comment: Have you tried sending an email to the device from another email account or even a normal SMS message to make sure the device can receive messages.

Comment: Yes. If i send a text directly from a cell phone it accepts the commands without a problem. It sends an 'ok' message. It just doesn't want to accept a message from my server.

Comment: Your server might have been blacklisted by the tmobile server so the message might be being denied. One solution might be to move towards something like Mailgun. You can setup a free account and send messages through them up to a certain limit (its a lot) this would allow you to test if its just a weird issue with blacklists.

Answer (score 0):

Some mail servers reject messages if they don't meet some minimal requirements for a safe and secure email message. Before that, you should check:

- Check the SMTP log after running your script if there was any error message (activated when you put `$phpMail->SMTPDebug = 2;`)
- If you can access the webmail interface for XXXXXXXXXX@tmomail.net, check if your messages are moved to a junk/spam folder.

When you compose the smtp message, some servers expects some minimal info, in order to check if the message is secure:

- From: Generally, the same as SMTP username (a valid email address)
- Subject: A simple subject, not empty
- Body: Don't put links in the content